Is there a higher-variable notion of class?
In ZFC, a class is just a formula with one free variable $x$. Some classes form sets, and some don't. However, is there a higher-variable notion of class? Perhaps they would be called "relation classes"? For example, consider the "relation class" $x \subseteq y$, that is, the relation holding between two sets $x$ and $y$ iff $x$ is a subset of $y$. It is a proper "relation class", because it does not form a set. Anyway, my real question is, has this notion been studied before in the mathematical literature? If so, can I see some references?

The usual term is "class relation" (or "class function" where appropriate). But there's no difference between these and normal classes: a tuple is a set after all (via Kuratowski), and so a class relation literally is a class in the usual sense.
